# Como posso validar campos vazios com cypress

Tags: javascript, testes, ui, testes-funcionais, cypress

Já tenho um método que valida quando eles têm alguma informação sobre ele, mas quando não há nada ele não acha o elemento da lista.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('selectedFilterPlan', (filterId, idComponentList) => {
  cy.get(filterId).should('be.visible');
  cy.get(filterId).should('have.value', '');
  cy.get(filterId)
  .then((selects) => {
    let select = selects[0];
    cy.wrap(select).click();
      if(cy.get(idComponentList).should("be.visible")){
        cy.get(idComponentList)
        .get("nz-option-item")
        .then(function(item) {
        cy.wrap(item[0]).click();
        cy.wait(500);
        cy.get("[data-cy=result-filter-list]").should("be.visible");
        });
      }
 });
});
```

---

```
it('select dropdown plan filters', () => {
  cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-1]', "#cdk-overlay-1");
  cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-2]', "#cdk-overlay-2");
  cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-3]', "#cdk-overlay-3");
  cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-4]', "#cdk-overlay-4");
  cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-5]', "#cdk-overlay-5");
});
```

O filtro quando está vazio, é exibido um Empty do Ant Design of Angular, conforme mostra a imagem a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou conseguindo validar quando o dropdown é aberto, pois é exibida a lista com seu respectivo conteúdo ou é exibido o Empty.